# Polychoric PCA and component loadings in Stata

Tags: correlation, pca, categorical-data, stata, ordinal-data

I’m using Stata 12.0, and I’ve downloaded the `polychoricpca` command written by Stas Kolenikov, which I wanted to use with data that includes a mix of categorical and continuous variables. Given the number of variables (around 25), my hunch is that I will need to generate more than 3 components. Ultimately, I would like to generate a handful of meaningful components (rather than dozens of variables) and use the components as independent variables in logistic regression.

Using `polychoricpca`, I am able to generate a table showing the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors (loadings) for each variable for the first three (3) components only. `polychoricpca` appears to call these loadings “scoring coefficients” and produces these for every level of the variable, such that if a variable has three categories you’ll see three scoring coefficients (“loadings”) for that variable.  Never having worked with polychoric PCA before, I’m used to only seeing one loading per variable/item. I want to examine these coefficients (“loadings”) to try to understand what the components are and how they might be labelled.

My questions:

(1) What if it looks as if I should generate 4 components? It seems as if I wouldn’t be able to examine and understand what that 4th component is because I can’t see how each of the items load on that 4th component, only the first 3. Is there a way to see how each item loads on more than the first three components?

(2) Can I simply use the polychoric correlation matrix combined with Stata’s `pcamat` command to examine how each item loads on each component (the eigenvector table). I thought this might be a way of being able to examine loadings if I have more than 3 components. The idea came from [this UCLA stats help post](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/faq/efa_categorical.htm) on using `factormat` with a polychoric correlation matrix. `pcamat` in Stata, however, produces only 1 loading (coefficient) per variable, not 1 loading for every level of the variable. Any thoughts on whether it would be appropriate just to report the single loading from `pcamat`?

Comment: I suspect that "scoring coefficients" are neither eigenvectors nor loadings, but are coefficients to compute component scores.

Comment: In polychoric PCA, we cannot compute scores directly from eigenvectors or loadings. We need a special algorithm https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/215483/3277.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can store all scores in variables, you cannot display the weights for all of them. But as they are important for a meaningful interpretation of the components, you could use the generated variables containing the score to get back on the weights.